# No longer seeing "Remove" in the contact record for smart groups

Tags: smartgroups

Are other also no longer seeing any way to remove a contact from a smart group from within the contact record? "Remove" and other action links are no longer displayed since I upgraded to 5.50. Now , for the smart groups, it only shows the "Group" and "Description" columns. I am seeing this on 2 Wordpress sites and 1 D7 site. I am also seeing this on one of the sandboxes.

Comment: What version were you on before?

Comment: I think I was on different versions on the different sites and I'm not sure when the ability to remove a contact from a smart group disappeared. I'm pretty sure it used to be similar to regular groups when looking at a contact record.